# Selenium Webdriver Python clicking radio button is showing WebElement object is not callable

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on a radio button on a webpage which I am automating in Selenium Webdriver Python.
When my code tries to click on the radio button it is showing the error:
TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not callable:

The full error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Webdriver\ClearCore\TestCases\MatchConfigrationPage_TestCase.py", line 85, in test_add_match_configuration_possibles_name
    possibles_match_rules_tab.click_selected_rule_radio_button("Name")
  File "C:\Webdriver\ClearCore\Pages\match_rules_tab.py", line 82, in click_selected_rule_radio_button
    radio_button = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//table[@id="match_configuration_add_possible_tab_match_rules_ct_mapping_body"]//span[@title="Name" and contains(text(), "Name")]//ancestor::tr[1]//input[@type="radio"]')
TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not callable
```

I can find the button using the following XPATH in Firefox XPATH checker.

```
//table[@id="match_configuration_add_possible_tab_match_rules_ct_mapping_body"]//span[@title="Name" and contains(text(), "Name")]//ancestor::tr[1]//input[@type="radio"]
```

My method to call the button and click is as follows:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

def click_selected_rule_radio_button(self, name):
    # params name: The name of the data object to be selected for the match rule, e.g. Name, Address
    radio_button = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//table[@id="match_configuration_add_possible_tab_match_rules_ct_mapping_body"]//span[@title="%s" and contains(text(), "%s")]//ancestor::tr[1]//input[@type="radio"]' (name, name))
    self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", radio_button)
    return self
```

the name parameter in the method it's value is "Name", %s in the code has the value "Name"

I have also tried the following:

```
def click_selected_rule_radio_button2(self, name):
    # params name: The name of the data object to be selected for the match rule, e.g. Name, Address
    #WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.ID, 'match_configuration_add_possible_tab_match_rules_ct_mapping_body')))
    radio_button = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//table[@id="match_configuration_add_possible_tab_match_rules_ct_mapping_body"]//span[@title="Name" and contains(text(), "Name")]//ancestor::tr[1]//input[@type="radio"]')))
    radio_button.click()
    return self
```

From my TestCase class i call the method as follows:

```
possibles_match_rules_tab.click_selected_rule_radio_button("Name")
```

code snippet of test case is as follows:

```
def test_add_match_configuration_possibles_name(self):
        print "*** Test add Match Configuration Possibles - Name ***"
        projectNavigator = project_navigator.ProjectNavigatorPage(self.driver)
        possiblesPage = projectNavigator.select_projectNavigator_item("Possibles") # click Possibles from project navigator
        possiblesPage.click_add_possibles_button()
        possiblesPage.enter_possible_matches_name_and_description_from_details_tab("name_dob", "date of birth possible match rule")
        possibles_match_rules_tab = possiblesPage.click_match_rules_tab()
        possibles_match_rules_tab.click_possibles_match_rules_add_button()
        possibles_match_rules_tab.enter_match_rule_name("name_dob")
        possibles_match_rules_tab.click_selected_rule_radio_button("Name")
```

The HTML is:

```
<table id="match_configuration_add_possible_tab_match_rules_ct_mapping_body" cellspacing="0" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;">
<colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="GPI5XK1CFG" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="0">
            <td class="GPI5XK1CEG GPI5XK1CGG GPI5XK1CHG">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-339" style="outline-style:none;" tabindex="0">
                    <input type="radio" name="rbCrossRow2" />
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GPI5XK1CEG GPI5XK1CGG">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-340" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <span class="" title="Name" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">Name</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GPI5XK1CEG GPI5XK1CGG GPI5XK1CBH">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-341" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <input id="match_configuration_add_possible_tab_match_rules_cb_name" type="checkbox" />
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="GPI5XK1CEH" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="1">
            <td class="GPI5XK1CEG GPI5XK1CFH GPI5XK1CHG">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-339" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <input type="radio" name="rbCrossRow2" />
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GPI5XK1CEG GPI5XK1CFH">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-340" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <span class="" title="Address" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">Address</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GPI5XK1CEG GPI5XK1CFH GPI5XK1CBH">
        </tr>
        <tr class="GPI5XK1CFG" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="2">
            <tr class="GPI5XK1CEH" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="3">
    </tbody>
```

Can anyone see what is wrong, why the radio button is not callable, it will not click it?

Thanks,
Riaz

Answer (score -1):

You can use JavaScript to click radio button.Code is as follow:

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('your URL')
time.sleep(10)
radioButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("Radio Button Xpath") #like //input[@id='female']
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", radioButton)
#driver.quit()
```

Comment: If you look at my question I have already tried the JavaScript code.